# The scaled boundary value residual error in NDSolveValue

Tags: warning-messages, error-tracking

What is the reason behind getting the following error?

```
NDSolveValue::berr: The scaled boundary value residual error of 26.66510579827707` indicates that the boundary values are not satisfied to specified tolerances. Returning the best solution found.
```

When I run the below-mentioned code, I get the graph perfectly but before the appearance of my graph the error message comes up. I cannot understand the meaning of this error/warning. Can somebody please help me out? My code is mentioned below:

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"];
b = 150;
a = 15;   
es = 1;                                                 (*Element \
size for FEA*)
noofnode = IntegerPart[((b - a)/es) + 1];
init = 0 &;
eb = 380*10^9;     (*MPa*)
ea = 71*10^9;       (*MPa*)
new = 0.3;                             (*Poisson's Ratio*)            \
      
gama = ea/(3*(1 - 2*new));  (*Bulk Modulus of A*)
miua = ea/(2*(1 + new));      (*Shear Modulus of A*)
gamb = eb/(3*(1 - 2*new));    (*Bulk Modulus of B*)
miub = eb/(2*(1 + new));         (*Shear Modulus of B*)
alpha = 23.1*10^(-6);
row = 2.70;
Y = (miu*(9*gam + 8*miu))/(6*gam + 12*miu);
ta = 20;                      (*Degree C*)
tb = 100;  
xa = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];  
xad = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];  
f3[a5_] := (1*a5) + 0;
c = 0;
For[u1 = a, u1 < b + es, u1 += es,
 c = c + 1;
 c11 = (u1 - a)/(b - a);
 xa[[c]] = f3[c11];
 ];                  (*Degree C*)
c = 0;
For[u1 = a, u1 < b + es, u1 += es,
  c = c + 1;
  c11 = (b - u1)/(b - a);
  xad[[c]] = c11;
  ]; 
rpm = 150.0;
wom = (2.0*\[Pi]*rpm)/60;
kb = 35.0;
ka = 204.0;
lam = (1/(b - a))*
  Log[kb/ka];               (*Constant for Exponential Temp Profile*)


f[ri_] := ExpIntegralEi[-lam*ri];
c1 = (tb - ta)/(f[b] - f[a]);
c2 = ((ta*f[b]) - (tb*f[a]))/(f[b] - f[a]);
T[r_] := c2 + c1*ExpIntegralEi[-lam*r];
xad = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}]; 
Va = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}]; 
ed = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];      
c = 0;
For[u1 = a, u1 < b + es, u1 += es, c = c + 1;
 c11 = (b - u1)/(b - a);
 xad[[c]] = 
  c11;];                              (*Modulus of Elasticity*)       \
            
For[ex = 1, ex < noofnode + 1, ex++,
 Va[[ex]] = xad[[ex]];
 x = Values[
   NSolve[Va[[
         ex]]*((gama - gam)/(3*gama + 4*miu)) + (1 - 
          Va[[ex]])*((gamb - gam)/(3*gamb + 4*miu)) == 0 &&
     Va[[ex]]*((miua - miu)/(miua + Y)) + (1 - 
          Va[[ex]])*((miub - miu)/(miub + Y)) == 0, {gam, miu}, 
    Reals]];
 x2 = Dimensions[x];
 gam = x[[x2[[1]], 1]];
 miu = x[[x2[[1]], 2]];
 ed[[ex]] = (9*gam*miu)/(3*gam + miu);
 Clear[gam, miu];
 ];
e = Interpolation[ed];
z = NDSolveValue[{(-F[r] + 
      r (F'[r] + 
         r ((3 + new) r row wom^2 + alpha e [r - 14] T[r] + 
            F''[r])))/(e [r - 14] r) == 0, F[a] == 0, F[b] == 0}, 
   F, {r, a, b}];
sol = Array[init, {noofnode, 1}];          
y = 0;
For[i = a, i < b + 1, i++,
  y = y + 1;
  sol[[y]] = (z[i]*10^(-9))/i;
  ];
ListLinePlot[sol]
```

Is there any mistake in my code for which I am getting the error? Here, `e` is the interpolation function that is varying continuously over the domain. However, If I take `e` as a fixed value in that case the error doesn't come but I need `e` as an interpolation function. How can I avoid this error? Or can I ignore this?

Comment: Please include enough Mathematica code so that respondents can replicate the same problem in their notebooks. It is called a `minimal working example`. Thanks.

Comment: @Syed I have added all credentials now.

Comment: You have a typo in" F^\[Prime]\[Prime]" . Should read either `Derivative[2][F][x]` or `F''[x]`

Comment: @DanielHuber I have written `F''[x]` but somehow here it is showing "F^[Prime][Prime]"

Comment: I can no reproduce this. In any case, the correct syntax would be  with backlashes: "F^\[Prime]\[Prime]" Or try the first possibility: `Derivative[2][F][x]`

Comment: @DanielHuber Now it will work. Because of copy-paste from Mathematica to Google Chrome, some characters got changed, unfortunately. I have edited those.